# when we teach delinquents to behave well, What verb exactly describes our activity?

Tags: word-request

In the following sentence, what is a perfect substitution for the word **train**?

> We have to teach teenage delinquents and **train** them today so they do not
> become pickpockets and shoplifters tomorrow.

train is too general. I need a more specific word that describes the activity of helping a teenager learn the rules and function well in society.

Comment: may be rehabilitate ?

Comment: What *exactly* is the additional process (over and above already-specified ***teach***) that you want to refer to here? I can't see why you don't simply remove ***and train them***, since it just seems to repeat what you've already said (but perhaps neither ***teach*** nor ***train*** is exactly "le mot juste").

Comment: We have to teach teenage offenders **to modify their behavior**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers +1 for using a French phrase on the English Language Learners exchange!  (Illustrating the adoption of appropriate phrases into English usage which is one thing that makes English such an international language).

Comment: "reform"........

Answer (score 1):

Well, the terms for the two most common paradigms of justice are *restorative* justice and *retributive* justice.

You could thereby say "restore", but "rehabilitate", and "reintegrate" also fit swell.

"Rehabilitate" literally means "make able again" re(again)habili(able)tate(make), so I would opt for this one — all struggling humans are just individuals who need to be made able again, through whichever means necesssary. I would use a different word than "delinquents", like "troubled kids/teenagers". It's a bit more humanizing.

---

EDIT:

The connotation for "able" on "rehabilitate" is to be made *socially able* in the *"normal"* manner. It is typically a process done to those who have broken laws.

Comment: And, more importantly, "rehabilitate" refers to the process of making criminals law-abiding members of society again.

Comment: @nick012000 Ah yes, I should have mentioned that. Edited. 

"able" in the socially connotated sense means "able (to be raced in a rat-like manner)", though.

Comment: The latin verb habilitare means to make fit (for purpose) - rehabilitation is also widely used in a medical context - which fits in nicely

Comment: I like your answer, but it seems clear to me that the question is about preemptive action before crimes take place and therefore before the consideration of justice.

Comment: @LifelongLearner Check out this [Wiktionary link on habilitāre](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/habilito#Latin). Making someone able to be in society feels no different in my mind than making someone fit/suitable for being in society. The addition of the re+ just meaning "again" here, of course. To raise a child is to habilitate a child, in this sense. How are "made able" and "made suitable (for)" different from each other?

Comment: @LifelongLearner Also, thank you! I like that it is used in a medical sense as well. So many of the nicest common words come from the sciences. One thing, though: I fail to see how the 4th subcomment on this comment is relevant. We are "rehabilitating" them because they are "troubled", no?

Comment: @AlexanderArgyropoulos Yes I agree, "fit (for purpose)" fits in nicely, making somone fit to to function as a member of society.

Comment: @AlexanderArgyropoulos It's not entirely clear from the sentence we were given, but at the end of the sentence the OP has "so they do not become" indicating that no crime has taken place.  I think we could still use the word rehabilitate here, but you phrased your answer in the context of restorative (rehabilitative) justice.  That's the only point I was making.

Comment: @LifelongLearner Ahh, I see. That is clear. I guess this is a sort of grey area for what one considers worthy of being "restored" in the sense of restorative justice. I may have overshot that term's scope.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a perfect substitution for the word train - which is nearly impossible to answer without understanding exactly what you want to communicate.

How you express your meaning, and the emotion that is carried in that meaning, will depend on the audience you are communicating with.

I think the comments suggesting that 'train' and 'teach' mean the same thing are valid.  Repetition and alliteration can both be useful tools when communicating, but from your question I think you are looking for a word with more impact.

I might suggest replacing teach as well (explanations below) with something like this:

> We need to **mentor** troubled teenagers, **investing** in them today
> so they do not become  pickpockets and shoplifters tomorrow

Explanation of word choices:

Firstly I have replaced "teenage delinquents" with "troubled teenagers" this is to provide more empathy with them and less 'othering'

Secondly I replaced teach with mentor - teenagers have been taught all their lives but mentoring suggests a focus on personal development rather than imparting knowledge.

Thirdly I used invest to deliberately impart a sense of value - both current and future -in the activity (the mentoring) and the teenagers themselves.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Today, it would be called therapy or rehabilitation, or perhaps reintegration into society.  An older term for it was reform, and schools that do this were formerly called reform schools or reformatories, but that would sound quaint today.

Therapy connotes more of a mental-health approach, rehabilitation more of a penal one, and reform more of a religious one.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question, or a comment on the answer from @AlexanderArgyropoulos ?

Comment: @LifelongLearner The former.